# Pass thisValue from Javascript to PHP file

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using javascript and php to get autosuggestions.

```
    <div>
        <div>
            University Name:<input type="text" size="20" name="uni" value="" id="uniString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();">
        </div>

        <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When a user type a name, I show the results and I use the fill function to get the value. Everything works fine. But is there any way I can use the ''thisValue'' (which is the selected university) to print a dropdown list? I want to print the courses of the selected university, so I wrote this code:

```
function lookup(uniString) {
    if (uniString.length == 0) {
        // Make the suggestions box invisible
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("autosuggestions.php", {
            universityString: "" + uniString + ""
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup

function fill(thisValue) {
    if (thisValue) {
        $('#uniString').val(thisValue);
        var strURL = "findCourse.php?uniString=" + thisValue;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById('coursediv').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }
    } else {
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
    }
}
findCourse.php: $uni = $_POST['uniString'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE university.uni_name='$uniString' AND .......");
if ($query) {
    ....
}`enter code here`
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tested it with 'document.write( )'.. what thisValue prints and it prints the university name (that's what I want). But when I pass the value to the php file (getCourse.php), the resulted value is null.

Can anyone help me please? I'm pretty sure my question is stupid and sorry for that, I'm not really good in javascript.

Comment: in function lookup you pass universityString whereas your php script is expecting uniString. Why?

Comment: yeah I've created 2 PHP scripts. One for autosuggestions and One for dropdown lists. The first PHP script is expecting universityString, the second PHP script (findCourse.php) is expecting uniString :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
req.open("GET", strURL, true);

$uni = $_POST['uniString'];
```

You need to use $_GET in PHP, if you use get method in ajax.

Comment: So simple lol :P Thank you so much, I'm still getting some errors but at least now I have the value!

Answer (score 0):

In your following code, you should replace "universityString" by "uniString".

```
$.post("autosuggestions.php", {universityString: ""+uniString+""}, function(data){
  if(data.length >0) {
    $('#suggestions').show();
    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's the PHP file where I'm checking the autosuggestions :) "universityString" is correct. Here I do need to use "uniString" as you said: var strURL = "findCourse.php?uniString=" + thisValue;

Comment: OK, it's because of 2 PHP scripts. I just saw your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery .blur()

```
$('#uniString').blur(function() {
    if ( $('#uniString').val() =! '' )
    {
        // DO POST
    }
});
```

for more help please study [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)